# i made the following binary search algorithm, and I am trying to improve it. suggestions?

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

i am doing a homework assignment where I have to check large lists of numbers for a given number.  the list length is <= 20000, and I can be searching for just as many numbers.  if the number we are searching for is in the list, return the index of that number, otherwise, return -1.  here is what I did.

i wrote the following code, that outputsthe correct answer, but does not do it fast enough.  it has to be done in less than 1 second.

here is my binary search code:`I am looking for suggestions to make it faster.

```
def binary_search(list1, target):
  p = list1
  upper = len(list1)
  lower = 0
  found = False
  check = int((upper+lower)//2)
  while found == False:
    upper = len(list1)
    lower = 0    
    check = int(len(list1)//2)
    if list1[check] > target:
      list1 = list1[lower:check]
      check= int((len(list1))//2)
    if list1[check] < target:
      list1 = list1[check:upper]
      check = int((len(list1))//2)
    if list1[check] == target:
      found = True
      return p.index(target)
    if len(list1)==1:
      if target not in list1:
        return -1`
```

grateful for any help/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is that this is *not* a correctly written [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (see the algorithm there).

There is *no need* of `index(target)` to find the solution; a binary search is `O(lg n)` and so the very presence of index-of, being `O(n)`, violates this! As written, the entire "binary search" function could be replaced as `list1.index(value)` as it is "finding" the value index simply to "find" the value index.

The code is also slicing the lists which is *not needed*<sup>1</sup>; simply move the upper/lower indices to "hone in" on the value. The index of the found value is where the upper and lower bounds eventually meet.

Also, make sure that `list1` is really a list such that the item access is `O(1)`.

(And `int` is not needed with `//`.)

---

<sup>1</sup> I believe that the complexity is still `O(lg n)` with the slice, but it is a non-idiomatic binary search and adds additional overhead of creating new lists and copying the relevant items. It also doesn't allow the correct generation of the found item's index - at least without similar variable maintenance as found in a traditional implementation.

Comment: thank you for the input.  I will look into the binary search algorithm.  I do not understand what you mean by item access in o(1) though this is a list, not a hashed value.  and if I do not index, how can i return the index?

Comment: @user3205701 Not all *sequences* are the same. While it is likely that you are given a `list` (unless someone is feeling mean), an index-based binary search will only have the expected bounds if index look-ups are O(1) on the source.

Answer (score -1):

Try using else if's, for example if the value thats being checked is greater then you don't also need to check if its smaller.